# Getting SIGSEGV after the eclipse start

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I have recently setup SCALA Eclipse IDE and I have been getting this fatal just after I launch my eclipse (let say within a min or so).

Now most of the SIGSEGV posts on stackoverflow do get the area of problem or the way it can be tackled in the Problematic frame area. However, in my case, it just states the problematic frame. Can you please give me a direction in which I need to proceed?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=5321, tid=47349238024512
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_77-b03) (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.77-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /usr/local/scala-eclipse/core or core.5321
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/scala-eclipse/hs_err_pid5321.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Answer (score 1):

It is said, that you have core file `/usr/local/scala-eclipse/core`
and error file with more info `/usr/local/scala-eclipse/hs_err_pid5321.log`.
Did you open hs_err_pid5321.log ?  Did it contains more info ?

---

About core files : There is a nice GUI application `sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB` in sa-jdi.jar file ( in your jdk/lib directory). You can open core file in that tool and inspect file
[image]